# Why does the thrift docker image need go

Tags: docker, thrift

[This](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/Dockerfile#L19) docker file's goal is to:

> Goal: provide a thrift-compiler Docker image

I was just wondering why does this image need to install `golang`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to download the Golang binary package but only copies over `gofmt`. Looking at https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/19baeefd8c38d62085891d7956349601f79448b3/compiler/cpp/src/thrift/generate/t_go_generator.cc it seems that at one point they were running `gofmt` on the Golang generated code.

The comment for that part of code links to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-3893 which references pull request https://github.com/apache/thrift/pull/1061 where the feature was actually removed.

The specific commit (https://github.com/apache/thrift/commit/2007783e874d524a46b818598a45078448ecc53e) appears to be in 0.10 but not 0.9. So, along with the disabling of `gofmt` they probably just forgot to remove it from the image or decided it was just worth leaving as the feature could be fixed and re-enabled at a later date.

It might be worth opening an issue to ask the Thrift team about it and if it can be removed.

Comment: "*seems that at one point they were running gofmt on the Golang generated code.*" - that has been removed a while ago. `gofmt` is no longer called by the compiler. So if there is no point anymore, [please file a ticket. We also accept PRs](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/HowToContribute).